# Presist data in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux-toolkit, incognito-mode

I am facing an issue while working with two different sessions in my application. The first session is an admin dashboard and the second session is the client-side, which is in incognito mode. The incognito mode session works well until I refresh the page, and all data is lost. I am using redux-persist and redux-persist-storage for data persistence. However, it should be noted that both sessions have different data.

Can someone suggest a solution to this issue and help me persist the data even after refreshing the incognito session?

Comment: The very point of incognito mode is to NOT persist the data from that session. Use a second Browser.

Comment: Use a second profile on the browser. I run 3.

Comment: it's a client preference, i have to make it work on incognito